# Carbon > A textual month could not be found. Carbon::createFromFormat('j F Y', '7 maart 2019')

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, setlocale

I'm scraping data from an external site where the date is Dutch: 7 maart 2019. I'm trying to convert this to an Carbon object, but can't figure out how.

```
$value = '7 maart 2019';
$carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('j F Y', $value);

var_dump($carbon);
// "A textual month could not be found"
```

I also tried setting the locale to `nl` or `nl_NL`, but no luck.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$value = '7 maart 2019';
Carbon::setLocale('nl');
$carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('j F Y', $value);

var_dump($carbon);
// "A textual month could not be found"
```

The Carbon docs reference to the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) docs. This returns false with the sort-of same setup.

What am I missing here...?

Comment: I think you did a typing mistake. Would you please check  `$value = '7 maart 2019';` to `$value = '7 march 2019';`

Comment: “Maart” is march in dutch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Carbon is a layer on top of the native PHP datetime functionality which doesn't support localized parsing, only output can be localized. You would need to either write your own translator, or use a library like [date by jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/date) which supports translation before parsing:

> Methods such as parse and createFromFormat also support "reverse translations". When calling these methods with translated input, it will try to translate it to English before passing it to DateTime:

```php
$date = Date::createFromFormat('l d F Y', 'zaterdag 21 maart 2015');
```